# Displaying JSON file onto the browser using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajax, express

I am creating a localhost server and reading the file path and later read the json file

I am passing the file path in the url.
Something like this: http://localhost:3000/C:/Users/Desktop/generated.json

server-side-code

```
var createError = require("http-errors");
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var PORT = 3000;
var fs = require("fs");
var app = express();
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

const url = require("url");
app.use(function(req, res) {
  let k = req.originalUrl;
  file = k.slice(1);


  fs.exists(file, function(exists) {
    fs.readFile(file, "utf-8", (error, data) => {
      if (error) throw error;
      let jsonData = [];
      jsonData.push(data);
      console.log(jsonData);//just displaying in console
      console.log(data);
      res.render("./main.ejs", { jsonData: jsonData });
    });
  });
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log(`app is listening at port ${PORT}`);
});
```

this is the client side code using ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head contentType="application/JSON">


</head>

<body>
    <form>
            <h1>
            <%=JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonData)) %>
        </h1>
            <br />
        <button name="Click to edit" type="submit" style="height:100px ;width:200px ;font-size:20px">
            Click to edit
        </button>
    </form>
</body>

</body>

</html>
```

The output displayed is something like this:
[the link to the output how it is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2eOy.png)

So I am not able to display it in a proper way.
Any idea how i can do it?

Even if I want to make changes to the json file and reflect the changes at the destination location

I haven't Added any functionality to the edit button yet.

Comment: `<%= JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonData)) %>` is entirely pointless. You parse `jsonData`, which is a string, into an object, and then immediately turn it back into a string again. You get out exactly what you put in. `<%= jsonData %>` would produce exactly the same result without all the extra processing.

Comment: Anyway what do you mean display it in a "proper" way...we don't know what your definition of "proper" is. Please give an example of your desired output. Anyway, if you want it to be editable, you probably want to put it into a textarea, and then set up your form correctly so it'll post the data back to the server again for you to save it back to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you mean you wan't it to be "pretty printed", something like

```
{
  "key": "value",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

instead of being 1 long line...

If that's the case, then you could do:

```
<code><pre><%=JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonData), null, 2) %></pre></code>
```

The 3rd parameter to `stringify` tells it how many spaces to use as indentation, and will have it pretty print the JSON onto multiple lines instead of 1 long line.

The `<code>` tag typically has a default styling of a monospace font, which makes the characters line up nicer.

The `<pre>` tag tells the browser that the contents are pre-formatted; whitespace and newlines should be preserved.

---

Also, note that you should ***never*** expose the above code to the public internet. It is a huge security hole. You are allowing anyone to read any file off your hard drive. There are numerous articles about this, but here is one example that talks about this security risk:

https://blog.rapid7.com/2016/07/29/pentesting-in-the-real-world-local-file-inclusion-with-windows-server-files/

Comment: thank you so much ,ya i will see the article thank you

Answer (score -1):

Please use the `<pre>` tag for this.

```
<pre>
    <%=JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonData)) %>
</pre>
```

Example:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1> Below is the code without pre </h1>
  [ { "userId": 1, "id": 1, "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit", "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem
  sunt rem eveniet architecto" }, { "userId": 1, "id": 2, "title": "qui est esse", "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui
  aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla" } ]

  <h1> Below is the code with pre </h1>
  <pre>
     [
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "qui est esse",
        "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
      }
     ]
     </pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `<%= JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonData)) %>` is entirely pointless. You parse jsonData, which is a string, into an object, and then immediately turn it back into a string again. You get out exactly what you put in.

Comment: Anyway, how do you know this is the solution? OP has said they don't like the output, but hasn't specified what they want it to look like instead. "proper way" is not a definition anyone can use to produce a GUI. So really, the question is impossible to answer currently.

Comment: Pre works for json formatting anyway. Hope it will solve the problem @crazycoder

Comment: Sure it works for JSON formatting in a certain style, but we don't actually know for sure if that's what OP wanted. For all we know maybe they wanted to make a HTML table out of it or something. And then they started talking about editing it, so maybe they want it in a form element like a textarea. It's completely unclear